# Why Mongoose cant create an index in MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have a Mongoose Schema which contains a field with a certain index:

```
const reportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    coords: {
    type: [Number],
    required: true,
    index: '2dsphere'
    },
…
}
```

It works well on my local machine, so when I connect to MongoDB through the shell I get this output for `db.reports.getIndexes()`:

```
[
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "weatherApp.reports"
},
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "coords" : "2dsphere"
    },
    "name" : "coords_2dsphere",
    "ns" : "weatherApp.reports",
    "background" : true,
    "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
}
]
```

Then I deploy this app to Heroku and connect to MongoDB Atlas instead of my local database. It works well for saving and retrieving data, but did not create indexes (only default one):

```
[
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "weatherApp.reports"
}
]
```

What may cause this problem? Atlas allow to create indexes through Web GUI and it works good as well as creating indexes form the shell. But Mongoose fails this operation for some reason.

Comment: can you check atlas logs ? Also, you automigrate your data ? after inserting data the index still not there ?

Comment: @anouarKacem, no, after inserting data there's still no index. Tried to check the logs on Atlas, but actually couldn't figure out where to get an access to them.

Comment: @MishaGoncharov did you ever find out what the issue was?

Comment: @Joseph, unfortunately, no. Atlas Support didn't help as well :-(

Comment: @MishaGoncharov I just figured out what was wrong for me. I'll submit an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue when I was on mongoose version `v5.0.16`. However, since I updated to `v5.3.6` it is now creating the (compound) indexes for me on Mongo Atlas. (I just wrote a sample app with both versions to verify this is the case).

I'm not sure which version fixed this issue, but it's somewhere between `v5.0.16` and `v5.3.6`, where `v5.3.6` is working.

Comment: Wow, I use 5.2.13. Gonna update it and check it out, thank you

Comment: Yes, it helped!

Comment: @MishaGoncharov glad to hear it!